# Ошибка при вводе: ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, float

Код:

```
a, b, c = map(float, input().split(' '))
```

Но при проверке на сайте следующая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "595bd828-ce3d-4d8b-9055-47517a8a18c0", line 3, in <module>
    a, b, c = map(float, input().split(' '))
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Я не могу понять, какие значения могут ее воспроизвести. По условию:

```
-10000<=a, b, c <=10000
Они могут быть любого типа (не только целые)
разделены пробелами
```

Comment: @jfs Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно проверять на пустую строку в `input()`.

---

Судя по ошибке `ValueError: could not convert string to float:` была получена пустая строка:

```
>>> float('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Чтобы повторить ошибку достаточно:

```
>>> list(map(float, ''.split(' ')))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: не обязательно пустая строка. Может быть более одного пробела `'1  2 3'`, другие пробельные символы: `'1\t2\t3'`, хвостовой пробел `'1 2 3 '`. Решение:  использовать split() вместо split(' ')